# Wordpress and Conditions

Tags: php

this might sound stupid to most dudes around, but, I have this code:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ( in_category('123') ) { ?>
<div class="pdfbox">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('pdfs'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="pdfbox">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('pdfs'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The thing is, how to add another category, like if is category 1 then output, HTML, if 2 the next html, if 3, so on so on..

Thanks!

Comment: can you clear to us, do you want to check in the category or is the category? You mention in the code 'in_category' but said within your question 'if is category'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you might be looking for here is the elseif statement...

```
<?php if ( in_category('123') ) { ?>
<div class="pdfbox">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('pdfs'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php } elseif ( in_category('125') ) { ?>
<div class="pdfbox">
<h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('pdfs'); ?></a>
</div>
<?php } ?> { ?>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Simon, so, using this approach I can have as many categories as I want, for example:

`<?php if ( in_category('123') ) { ?>

HTML GOES HERE

<?php } elseif ( in_category('124') ) { ?>

HTML GOES HERE

<?php } elseif ( in_category('125') ) { ?>

HTML GOES HERE

<?php } elseif ( in_category('126') ) { ?>

HTML GOES HERE

<?php } elseif ( in_category('127') ) { ?>

HTML GOES HERE

<?php } ?> { ?>`

Comment: BTW, is the closing PHP tag ok? seems like something there is throwing me an error but not sure what.

Comment: What's your error bru?